# How to run .apk in emulator outside of eclipse

Tags: android-emulator

I have an apk file that I would like to run in the emulators but outside of eclipse.I see in the tools directory of the android sdk there is an emulator app but is there a way to test outside of eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sorry I am on windows friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can test it outside eclipse.

1. Run android.exe and add a virtual device
2. Launch the emulator with `emulator -avd YourVirtualDevice`
3. Run your apk with `adb install yourfile.apk`

Comment: pkg: /data/local/tmp/test.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS] This is a signed and zipaligned file.

Answer (score 0):

If it is saying "failed and already exists" means: the apk which you are trying to install is already installed on the emaulator or the device.

Goto Settings--> Manage Applications --> Select the app (which you are trying to install) --> uninstall..

Now try; it should work.